# Azure Pipeline: Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

this is my pipeline:

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Install NuGet >=6.3.0-0'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '>=6.3.0-0'
    checkLatest: true
    
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: Use DotNet Version 7.0.x
  inputs:
    version: '7.0.x'
    includePreviewVersions: true # Required for preview versions

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Nuget Restore Packages'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '11b33a23-a7bd-4e05-bce5-7383e054c4f4/3aef100d-2005-4893-9c82-65ed96a2b539'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build Web API projects'
  inputs:
    command: build
    projects: '**/*src/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)' # Update this to match your need

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build Database Migrator'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/*tools/*DatabaseMigrator.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/App_Data/jobs/triggered -r win-x64 --self-contained false'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build Frequently Operations'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/*tools/*FrequentlyOperations.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/App_Data/jobs/continuous -r win-x64 --self-contained false'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Create Zip Build For Release'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: true

# this code takes all the files in $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) and uploads them as an artifact of your build.
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact(Zip File) For Release'
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
    artifactName: 'output'
```

when it is triggered it shows this error:

> Starting: Build Web API projects
> ==============================================================================
> Task         : .NET Core
> Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
> Version      : 2.210.0
> Author       : Microsoft Corporation
> Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
> ==============================================================================
> C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
> Active code page: 65001
> Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.
> Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain .Net 5.x SDK/Runtime along with the older .Net Core version which are currently lts. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 5.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions. You can learn more about the breaking changes here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/ and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/ . To learn about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
> ##[error]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.
> Finishing: Build Web API projects

this is my project:

[image]

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ##[error]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.

Reproduce the same issue  when the csproj file is not in the root node of the src folder.

For example:

```
-- src 
  --projectname
   -- xxx.csproj 
  -- projectname1
```

Usually the src folder will contain multiple project folders.

To solve this issue, you need to check the src folder structure and define the folder path of the dotnet task.

For example:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build Web API projects'
  inputs:
    command: build
    projects: '**/*src/** or subfolder name/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot of your repo, I didn't see a **csproj** in your project.
You need to have a csproj in your project.
You could also use **sln** to restore and build your project.

```
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
  inputs:
    version: 5.0.x
    performMultiLevelLookup: true
    includePreviewVersions: true # Required for preview versions
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.sln'
  displayName: 'Restore Nuget Packages'
 
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.sln'
    arguments: '--no-restore'
  displayName: 'Build projects'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
   command: 'publish'
   publishWebProjects: true
   arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1    
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'api.chibebinam'
```

Comment: sorru, i posted the wrong pipeline. Now is correct @jiawei shi

Comment: could you please confirm that if the .csproj is in the root directory of src?

Comment: yes, it is in the root directory

Comment: Commonly, this error caused by that the projects argument failed to find the .csproj.
Could you please share a screenshot of the structure of your .csproj in the repo?